# Оплата на сайте так, чтоб деньги поступал на счет в банке

Tags: веб-программирование

Здравствуйте! Возможно ли сделать так, чтоб после оплаты на сайте (например с визы) деньги поступали на счет в банке (например сбербанк)?

Comment: ищите информацию по api. может вам подойдут платежные посредники.

Comment: Спасибо! попробую поискать.

Comment: Да, только не в счет а в расчетный счет можно, для этого просто напишите к сервису(какую вы установили), они вам отправят список копии документов, вы отправляете они вам сделаю)))

Answer (score 3):

Здравствуйте! Попробуйте Робокассу, там есть возможность принимать денежные средства на свой Банковский счёт. [Перейти на робокассу](http://robokassa.ru/ru/)

Comment: Большое спасибо! попробую

Comment: Робокасса шлак... Не советую